# res.render não carrega .handlerbars dentro rota - Node.JS e Handlerbars

Tags: node.js, express.js, handlebars.js

Boa noite!

Estou aprendendo Node.JS e estou travado nas rotas.

Tenho os seguintes códigos.

```
//app.js

// carregando modulos
const express = require('express')
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const admin = require('./routes/admin')
const path = require('path')

// const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Configs
// body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
    app.set('view engine','handlebars')
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
// mongoose

// Public  
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('Rota principal!')

})
app.get('/posts', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('Lista Posts')
})
app.use('/admin',admin)
// Others
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server Run!");
})

//routes/admin.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('partials/_navbar')
})

router.get('/posts',(req, res)=>{
    res.send('Página de posts')
})

router.get('/categorias', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("Página categorias")
})

module.exports = router
```

e recebendo o seguinte erro

```
Error: Module "handlebars" does not provide a view engine.
at new View (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:84:13)
at Function.render (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\routes\admin.js:5:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\blogapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

a intenção aqui é utilizar o layout chamando o `res.render`.

Estrutura de pastas

```
--blogapp
  --routes
  --views
    --layout
    --admin
```

Estou seguindo este tutorial, [Curso de Node.js - Arquivos estáticos #33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dghtXs5j__Q&list=PLJ_KhUnlXUPtbtLwaxxUxHqvcNQndmI4B&index=33)

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a [documentação da lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars), consegui reproduzir o seu problema. Acontece que é necessário você definir a view engine utilizando o método `app.engine`.

Para resolver o problema, basta você adicionar o conteúdo `app.engine('handlebars', handlebars());` antes da linha `app.set('view engine','handlebars')`.

> Segue código:

```
//app.js

// carregando modulos
const express = require('express')
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();
const admin = require('./routes/admin')
const path = require('path')

// const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Configs
// body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars());
    app.set('view engine','handlebars')
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
// mongoose

// Public  
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('Rota principal!')

})
app.get('/posts', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('Lista Posts')
})
app.use('/admin',admin)
// Others
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server Run!");
})

//routes/admin.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('partials/_navbar')
})

router.get('/posts',(req, res)=>{
    res.send('Página de posts')
})

router.get('/categorias', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("Página categorias")
})

module.exports = router
```

> **Importante:** Vale lembrar que não testei o seu código, mas consegui reproduzir o erro mencionado criando um novo projeto do zero e removendo essa linha (que é a única instrução não implementada em seu código porém que consta na documentação da lib).

Comment: Cara, deu um problema mesmo com essa solução, mas eu precisava mudar o nome da pasta layout para layouts, que estava errado também, e funcionou. Deu super certo, obrigado!

Comment: @FranckCosta fique a vontade em compartilhar o problema, assim eu altero a resposta para que ajude outros amigos no futuro.

Comment: A sua solução está correta, havia outro problema que eu não tinha notado que a pasta layout não estava nomeada corretamente, que deveria ser layouts.

Comment: Ah sim bacana! Boa codada ai mano ;)